# Como pegar o mês em português utilizando o Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com duvidas em como pegar o valor do mês por extenso em português utilizando a *API* do **Carbon** utilizando o *framework* *Laravel*. Inicialmente, construi essa logica utilizando o PHP.

```
        if($data->month == 1){
            $mes = 'Janeiro';
        }
```

Isso acarreta fazer em torno de 12 if's para poder pegar o valor do mês em português. Supondo que a variável $data recebe o valor do tempo de agora.

```
        $data = Carbon::now();
```

Como poderia estar pegando o mês por extenso em portugues utilizando somente funções da *API* do **Carbon**? Como mostrado o exemplo abaixo.

```
        $mes = $data->localeMonth;
```

Por exemplo, hoje é pego o mês "*July*". Eu estou em duvida também em como posso mudar a localização para o horário oficial de Brasília. Creio que mudando a localização, pode-se resolver o meu problema. Mas está dificil encontrar na documentação da *API* a solução. Poderiam me ajudar?

[Documentação do Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: `Carbon::now()->settings(['locale' => 'pt_BR', 'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',]);` muda o locale?

Comment: aparece erro "Method settings does not exist."

Comment: Qual versão do laravel vc usa? e qual é a versão do carbon?

Comment: Carbon 1.26.3 e Laravel 5.8, talvez 5.7, não sei de certeza

Comment: Na documentação tem uma parte que fala como internacionalizar com o cabon 1.x que basicamente usa a função `strftime()` que pode ter o locale trocado diferente da classe DateTime.

Comment: aonde posso encontrar isso na documentação?

Comment: No like está na pergunta procure por  `version 1 documentation of Localization by clicking here.` ali tem alguns exemplos.

Comment: tentei usar o Carbon::executeWithLocale(), o Carbon::setLocale('de'), e chamei com $data->formatLocalized('%B'), porém persiste em exibir o mes em ingles. Não sei se poderia me ajudar, onde posso pegar todas as localizações que posso usar para testes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A documentação do Carbon notifica sobre a [localização](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) para a versão 1 da API:

> Unfortunately the base class `DateTime` does not have any localization
>   support. To begin localization support a `formatLocalized($format)`
>   method was added. The implementation makes a call to strftime using
>   the current instance timestamp. If you first set the current locale
>   with PHP function `setlocale()` then the string returned will be
>   formatted in the correct locale.

O objeto nativo do *PHP* `DateTime` não suporta internacionalização e ele é a classe base do Carbon. Mas a própria documentação fornece um código para auxiliar neste problema. Segue o código abaixo adaptado para a sua situação.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ptb'); // LC_TIME é formatação de data e hora com strftime()
$dt = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

---

Caso a instrução acima ainda não funcione, você pode "forçar" a internacionalização da seguinte maneira:

```
// Force locale
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'ptb', 'pt_BR', 'portuguese-brazil', 'portuguese-brazilian', 'bra', 'brazil', 'br');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'ptb', 'pt_BR', 'portuguese-brazil', 'portuguese-brazilian', 'bra', 'brazil', 'br');


// Create Carbon date
$dt = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

Comment: A instrução acima não funcionou, porém a de baixo funcionou direitinho. Muito agradecido pela resposta.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter te ajudado! :)

Answer (score 0):

No Laravel > 8 você pode definir o idioma no arquivo de configuração "config/app.php", alterando o valor da variável "locale" para "pt_BR":

```
'locale' => 'pt_BR',
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize da seguinte forma:

```
$dt->translatedFormat('l, d \d\e F, Y');
```

Comment: Essa resposta não está errada! se o projeto estiver confirado para "'locale' => 'pt_BR'"  como a resposta acima propoem,  o 'translatedFormat' vai funcionanr perfeitamente.