# O setlocale não funciona em instancias Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-aws

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em **Laravel** onde eu precisei utilizar os recursos da função `setlocale` para traduzir os meses de determinado dia em português. Há um mês atrás eu havia publicado uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400366/como-pegar-o-m%C3%AAs-em-portugu%C3%AAs-utilizando-o-carbon)  referente a essa funcionalidade realizada em **PHP**. Localmente em minha máquina ela funciona normalmente. Todos os meses são pegos de forma correta. Abaixo está o codigo que utilizei para "forçar" a localização e pegar os valores traduzidos.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'ptb', 'pt_BR', 'portuguese-brazil', 'portuguese-brazilian', 'bra', 'brazil', 'br');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'ptb', 'pt_BR', 'portuguese-brazil', 'portuguese-brazilian', 'bra', 'brazil', 'br');
```

Abaixo está o exemplo do que poderia pegar sua data. Onde utilizo o comando `formatLocalized('%B')`.

```
$mes = $datas->copy()->subMonth()->formatLocalized('%B');
```

Porém ocorreu um simples erro. Foi subido a minha funcionalidade para um servidor de uma instância do **Amazon EC2**, e os meses não saem em português, ambos os meses aparecem em inglês.

Encontrei alguém que possui o mesmo problema que o meu [nesse link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162237). Porém ainda me deixou com duvida do que pode ocorrer com isso. Lembrando que estou utilizando a *API* do **Carbon**. O que poderia ser esse problema, poderia ser da minha instância da **Amazon**?

> A versão do PHP da minha maquina local é a 7.3 e a do servidor Amazon é 7.2.

Comment: Já verificou se o locale que está utilizando está devidamente instalado no servidor (`$ locale -a`)?

Comment: Não estava instalado, deu certo. Porém deu outro erro agora. Usei o comando locale-gen pt_BR.utf-8. Depois disso, funcionou normalmente. Só que agora está ocorrendo de vezes aparecer traduzido e vezes aparecer em ingles.

Comment: É atualizado a página para isso acontecer. Eu instalei o pt_BR e o pt_BR.utf-8

Comment: Chegou a reiniciar o servidor após a instalação?

Comment: @ArthurAbitante responda sua pergunta com o que resolveu o problema e crie uma nova pergunta para o novo problema, vinculando esta pergunta na pergunta doravante.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ainda não, vou fazer isso.

Comment: @CypherPotato, ok, logo responderei a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não está na instância da Amazon. Isso ocorre quando o servidor linux da  sua instância da Amazon, não possui a localização desejada instalada. Para instalar em seu servidor, deve executar o seguinte comando no terminal (precisamente em servidores linux):

```
locale-gen pt_BR.utf-8
```

O pt_BR.utf-8 é utilizado para o idioma em portugues, podendo suportar caracteres como o "ç".Também tu poderá reconfigurar a sua localização manualmente, utilizando o comando abaixo. Procure por pt_BR.utf-8 para definir como padrão.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Ou poderá utilizar o comando abaixo para definir como *default* a sua localização.

```
sudo update-locale LANG=pt_BR.utf-8
```